# Python - Bokeh - Stacked, Grouped hbar_stack chart color control

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to use a stacked, grouped hbar_stack chart as a Gantt chart.

But I need more control over colors, and I can't figure the syntax.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

output_notebook()

starts = []
durations = []
Task1 = {'P1': (1, 9), 'P2': (2, 8), 'P3':(3, 7)}
Task2 = {'P1': (4 ,6), 'P2': (5, 5), 'P3':(6, 4)}
Task3 = {'P1': (7, 3), 'P2': (8, 2), 'P3':(9, 1)}

for value in Task1.values():
    starts.append(value[0])
    durations.append(value[1])
for value in Task2.values():
    starts.append(value[0])
    durations.append(value[1])
for value in Task3.values():
    starts.append(value[0])
    durations.append(value[1])    

factors = [
            ('Task 3', 'P1'), ('Task 3', 'P2'), ('Task 3', 'P3'),
            ('Task 2', 'P1'), ('Task 2', 'P2'), ('Task 2', 'P3'),
            ('Task 1', 'P1'), ('Task 1', 'P2'), ('Task 1', 'P3')
            ]

regions = ['start', 'duration']

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    y=factors,
    start =  starts,
    duration = durations

))

p = figure(y_range=FactorRange(*factors), plot_height=250,
           toolbar_location=None)

p.hbar_stack(regions, y='y', width=0.9, alpha=0.5, color=["red", 'blue'], source=source,
             legend_label = regions)

p.x_range.start = 0
p.x_range.end = 18
p.y_range.range_padding = .1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = 'black'
p.legend.location = "right"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
p.toolbar_location="below"

show(p)
```

Results in:

[image]

I want to control the colors of 'P1', 'P2' and 'P3' individually.

Effectively this means that I need to be able to set the colors of 18 bars individually (although all of the 'start' bars will be set to None.

Comment: You'll most likely need to use bare `hbar` (i.e. not `hbar_stack`) to have that level of control. It's possible there is some solution with a color mapper, but I don't know what it would be exactly, offhand.

Comment: Alternatively, three separate calls to `hbar_stack` could work (one for each of P1, P2, P3 if each of those gets their own color set)

Answer (score 0):

@bigreddot,

Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction.

Individual calls to hbar_stack looks to do what I need.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

output_notebook()
  
P1Start = [7, 4, 1]
P1Duration = [3, 6, 9]

P2Start = [8, 5, 2]
P2Duration = [2, 5, 8]

P3Start = [9, 6, 3]
P3Duration = [1, 4, 7]

factors = [
            ('Task 3', 'P1'), ('Task 3', 'P2'), ('Task 3', 'P3'),
            ('Task 2', 'P1'), ('Task 2', 'P2'), ('Task 2', 'P3'),
            ('Task 1', 'P1'), ('Task 1', 'P2'), ('Task 1', 'P3')
            ]

P1factors = [('Task 3', 'P1'), ('Task 2', 'P1'), ('Task 1', 'P1')]
P2factors = [('Task 3', 'P2'), ('Task 2', 'P2'), ('Task 1', 'P2')]
P3factors = [('Task 3', 'P3'), ('Task 2', 'P3'), ('Task 1', 'P3')]

regions = ['start', 'duration']

P1Source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(
    y = P1factors,
    start = P1Start,
    duration = P1Duration))

P2Source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(
    y = P2factors,
    start = P2Start,
    duration = P2Duration))

P3Source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(
    y = P3factors,
    start = P3Start,
    duration = P3Duration))

p = figure(y_range=FactorRange(*factors), plot_height=250,
           toolbar_location=None)

p.hbar_stack(['start', 'duration'], y='y', width=0.9, alpha=0.5, color=[None, 'blue'], source=P1Source)

p.hbar_stack(['start', 'duration'], y='y', width=0.9, alpha=0.5, color=[None, 'green'], source=P2Source)

p.hbar_stack(['start', 'duration'], y='y', width=0.9, alpha=0.5, color=[None, 'red'], source=P3Source)

p.x_range.start = 0
p.x_range.end = 20
p.y_range.range_padding = .1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = 'black'
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
p.toolbar_location="below"

show(p)
```

[image]
more...